# stop dropping duplicates in drag and drop javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to stop drag and dropping same item twice to the same location of the second item list (Drag Elements). But need to keep first item list (Sceintific Methods) as it is without disabling previously dropped items.Please let me know if this is possible.
 Following are my java-script functions

```
    const obj_observation= {
        name:"Observation",
        val: "observation"
        };
        const obj_literature_surey= {
        name:"Literature Survey",
        val: "literature_survey"
        };
        const obj_problem_definition= {
        name:"Problem Definition",
        val: "problem_definition"
        };
        const obj_theoretical_framework={
        name:"Theoretical Framework",
        val: "theoretical_framework"
        };

        const obj_hypothesis_development= {
        name:"Hypothesis Development",
        val: "hypothesis_development"
        };
        const obj_experimental_design= {
        name:"Experimental Design",
        val: "experimental_design"
        };
        const obj_data_collection={
        name:"Data Collection",
        val: "data_collection"
        };
        const obj_data_analysis= {
        name:"Data Analysis",
        val: "data_analysis"
        };
        const obj_conclusion = {
        name:"Conclusion",
        val: "conclusion"
        };


    var s_methods = [
    obj_observation,
    obj_literature_surey,
    obj_problem_definition,
        obj_theoretical_framework,
        obj_hypothesis_development,
        obj_experimental_design,
        obj_data_collection,
        obj_data_analysis,
        obj_conclusion
    ];


    var thesis_items = {
        introduction:{      
            name: "Introduction",
            vals:[obj_observation.val,obj_literature_surey.val,obj_problem_definition.val,obj_hypothesis_development.val]
        },
        lit_review:{
            name: "Literature Review",
            vals:[obj_literature_surey.val]
        },
        methodology:{
            name: "Methodology",
            vals:[obj_theoretical_framework.val,obj_experimental_design.val,obj_data_collection.val]
        },
        data_analysis:{
            name: "Data Analysis",
            vals:[obj_data_analysis.val]
        },
        conclusion:{
            name: "Conclusion",
            vals:[obj_conclusion.val]
        },


    };

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        console.log("allowDrop");
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        console.log("drag",ev.target.id);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

    }

    function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var dragId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var locId =  ev.target.id;

    console.log("HELLO");   
    console.log(locId, "   ",dragId);   
        const isOK = isDragOK(locId,dragId);
        if(isOK){
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(dragId));
      reRenderSMethods();
        }
}
    function selectMethod(){
    var index = document.getElementById("selectM").value;
    var opt = main_options[index];
    renderDragLocationsForMethods(opt);


    }
function renderSelectM(){
    const selectM = document.getElementById("selectM");
    selectM.innerHTML = '';
        for(var i=0 ; i< main_options.length ;i++){
            var item  = main_options[i];
            selectM.options[selectM.options.length] = new Option(item.name, i); 
        }

    }

    function reRenderSMethods(){
    const sMethods = document.getElementById("sMethods");
    sMethods.innerHTML = '';

    for(var i=0; i< s_methods.length; i++){
        var item = s_methods[i];
        var li = document.createElement("div");
    //  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        li.setAttribute('id',item.val);
          li.setAttribute('ondragstart','drag(event)');
          li.setAttribute('draggable',true);
          li.setAttribute('class','col-md-12'); 
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
    //  ul.appendChild(li);
        sMethods.appendChild(li);
    }

}

    function renderDragLocationsForMethods(obj){
        let val = obj.val;
        let headersObjs,headerKeys;

        const dElements = document.getElementById("dElements");
        dElements.innerHTML = '';

        if(val == "thesis"){
            headersObjs = thesis_items;

        }
        else{
            alert (obj.name);
            return;
        }

        headerKeys =  Object.keys(headersObjs);
        for(var i=0; i<headerKeys.length ; i++){
        var key = headerKeys[i];
        var item = headersObjs[key];
        var li = document.createElement("div");

        li.setAttribute('id',key);
        li.setAttribute('ondrop','drop(event)');
        li.setAttribute('ondragover','allowDrop(event)');
        li.setAttribute('class','col-md-12');   
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));

        dElements.appendChild(li);

        }

    }



    function callOnLoad(){
        renderSelectM();
        reRenderSMethods();

    }

    function dr(event, ui){
            var draggedID = ui.draggable.attr('id');
            var droppedID = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    function isDragOK(locId,dragId,droppedID){
        let isOK = false;
        var index = document.getElementById("selectM").value;
        var opt = main_options[index];
        if(opt.val == 'thesis'){
            var obj  = thesis_items[locId];
            const itemsArray  = obj.vals;   
            if(itemsArray.includes(dragId)){
                return true;

            }
        }

        return isOK;
    }
```

Following is my html code

```
    <div class="container">
   <div class="row container mt-3">
      <label for="selectM" class="col-md-3"> <b>Select Method</b></label>
      <select id="selectM" class="col-md-3 form-control" onchange="selectMethod()">
        <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="opt2" selected>Option 2</option>
        <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row container mt-3">
         <div class="col-md-6 p-5" style="background-color: #a6deef;">
          <label class="col-md-12"> <b>Sceintific Methods</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6" id="sMethods">
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 p-5" style="background-color: #d6dbf3;">
         <label class="col-md-12"><b> Drag Elements</b></label>
         <div class="col-md-12 " id="dElements">

         </div>
         </div> 

    </div>
    </div>
```